# How to convert class into json in javascript?

Tags: javascript, class

I need to get JSON object from class

I tried this, but I don't need initialization of class in constructor. And it would be perfect if I would get types of attributes in JSON object.

```
class ClassExamle {
    constructor(n) {
      this.name = n;
      this.mapOfClassExamle = new Map();
    }
}

function intoJSON(instance) {
    return JSON.stringify(instance, (key, value) => {
      if(value instanceof ClassExamle) {
        //only return serialisible fields
        const  { name, mapOfClassExamle } = value;
        //return plain object 
        return { name, mapOfClassExamle };
      }
      
      //convert map to plain object
      if(value instanceof Map) {
        return Object.fromEntries(value);
      }
  
      return value;
    });
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Cerbrus, I edited the question with extra explanations

Comment: have you tried `console.log(JSON.stringify(new ClassExamle(1))`

Comment: Yea, you can just stringify the class instance.

Comment: of course, the `Map` is problematic, since a JSON property value can't be an `Object`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any object in javascript can be converted to JSON using the `JSON.stringify` function. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

```js
JSON.stringify(yourClass);
```

So in your case it's:

```js
let exampleClass = new ClassExamle()
console.log(JSON.stringify(exampleClass));
```